# Dynamically select a list of properties from an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a collection IEnumerable.  In a LINQ query, preferably, I would like to select only the properties in this collection from type T, into an anonymous type, where T is a POCO business object.

Example:

My IEnumerable contains properties "Name", "Age".

My POCO is:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I want to achieve the same effect as below, but without hard-coding the members of the anonymous type, and instead using my PropertyInfo collection.

```
IEnumerable<Person> peeps = GetPeople();
var names = from p in peeps
            select new {Name = p.Name, Age = p.Age};
```

If I was using Entity Framework, I could use [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx) with a dynamically constructed string `where` clause, but then although not strictly hard-code, I'm still using string names of the properties.

Could I not perhaps dynamically construct an expression for the .Select projection method that determines which properties are included in the result object?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The compiler needs to know statically the type of the items in the enumeration, even if it's an anonymous type (the `var` keyword denotes *implicit* typing, not *dynamic* typing)

Why do you need to do that ? If you explain what your requirement is, we can probably suggest another way to do it

Comment: I'm exporting a collection of JobCard objects.  The properties of each object to be included in a CSV representation of the object depend on the user role.  At the moment I am just looping through a list of properties included for a role and usign reflection to get their values from each JobCard object. 

I only used 'var' as an example.  Could I not perhaps use 'dynamic'?  I know nothing about that though.

Comment: please see my edit.  I know I said "in a LINQ query", but just for interest, the limitation on the dynamic property set is platform dependent and can be achieved using Entity Framework.